# How to capture events in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm starting to learn about extensions in google chrome, but I'm a little lost, and I need to do something very simple, but do not know where to start.

My biggest question is how manifest.json works, read in several places but could not understand very well. After that, I need to make, whenever the user hovers the mouse over a link, or click a button, text area and input, returns a warning message on the console event.

I did some tests like console.log works but none worked, did not know how to do: (

I tried to do something like this: every time the user opens the browser, enables the extension and prints to the console it was started the same.

I think it would be so thank you and I hope answers.

Comment: Sounds like you need a content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms `manifest.json` is file where settings of your extensions stored. There are 3 kinds of actors in Chrome extension.

1. `Options page` : The page that is displayed as popup when you click on extension at the right corner of the chrome window.
2. `Background Scripts` : Background page / background scripts acts as server of your Chrome extension, it has all the permissions provided by Chrome. You can either mention background page or background script, but either of them should be used. Below I will mention few use cases of both of these. For example Chrome extension has clipboardEvents, and that works only in background scripts. But clipboard API requires DOM support. To make copy or paste of clipboard API work, we have to create textarea, then focus on it, execute paste event using `execCommand('paste')` and then get the textarea value, it gives clipboard content. If you know that you do not require any DOM related operations then depend only on background-scripts. Background script execution is asynchronous. Communication between background, content scripts and options page should be done through Chrome events API.
3. `Content Scripts` : If you want to inject any scripts or styles in to webpage where your extension is enabled, then content scripts are choices. Here is the power, whatever action performed in web page capture it with content scripts and then send it to background page /script for further processing then get the result back exactly as AJAX mechanism.

And for more information I highly recommend you to go through each and every section of http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html.

```
   "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://www.stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "css": ["yourPageStyles.css"], 
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"] // 
   }]
```

If you want to over ride any styles of stackoverflow, place it in `yourPageStyles.css` file, If you want to add any page level events, like you said hover and click events on links and buttons. Then place the code in `myscript.js`. myscript.js file code will be executed in stackoverflow.com web page context like regular js files did. But if you want to append any extension resources you have to use `getUrl()`. For example to add a image of you extension in web page make

```
 var srcUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('images/yourImage.png');
 someImage.src = srcUrl;
```

And before to that you have to make them web accessible resources to define what are the resources to be shared with web page. If you are using only in content script then it may not require to mention in web accessible resources.

Hope this helps.